# Target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit

Tags: ios, swift, webkit

I have developed a wrapper app that will load my PWA web application with WebView.
It runs but I get an error in the console. I use Xcode 15, min target SDK 13.
How can I fix this issue?

> Timestamp: 2023-12-28 16:06:03.591027+01:00 | Library: WebKit | Subsystem: com.apple.WebKit | Category: Process

> Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>

> Timestamp: 2023-12-28 16:06:07.170728+01:00 | Library: RunningBoardServices | Subsystem: com.apple.runningboard | Category: assertion

> 0x112027240 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'XPCConnectionTerminationWatchdog' for process with PID=51575, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}

> Timestamp: 2023-12-28 16:06:07.170777+01:00 | Library: WebKit | Subsystem: com.apple.WebKit | Category: ProcessSuspension

I am new to iOS and Xcode. I just searched on the Internet and Apple documents but didn't get much.

I just add the following to the webview.

```swift
webView.navigationDelegate = self
webView.uiDelegate = self
webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
webView.allowsLinkPreview = true
```